# How can I make a column into rows with pandas with a dynamic number of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a column of values into separate columns using pandas in python. So I have columns relating to shops and their products and the number of products each shop has could be different. For example:

```
ShopId  ShopCode  ShopName    ProductName
1       a         Shop One    x
1       a         Shop One    y
1       a         Shop One    z
2       b         Shop Two    2x
2       b         Shop Two    2y
3       c         Shop Three  3x
```

What I am trying to achieve would look something like this:

```
ShopId  ShopCode  ShopName    Product1  Product2  Product3
1       a         Shop One    x         y         z
2       b         Shop Two    2x        2y
3       c         Shop Three  3x
```

If there are any shops that have more than 3 products, I would need more columns to be created for them dynamically. Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter with reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
c = ['ShopId','ShopCode','ShopName']
g = df.groupby(c).cumcount()
df1 = (df.set_index(c + [g])['ProductName']
         .unstack(fill_value='')
         .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Product{x + 1}')
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
  ShopId ShopCode ShopName Product1 Product2 Product3
0      a     Shop      One        x        y        z
1      b     Shop      Two       2x       2y         
2      c     Shop    Three       3x
```